# Word to describe "not very old" movie

Tags: single-word-requests, cinema

The other day when we are talking about movies, I was kind of struggling to find the proper word to describe a movie that is **not very old**, but also **not quite new**.

For example, movies from around 2000, like *The Last Samurai (2003)* and *The Shawshank Redemption (1994)*. (I don't think they're old, but some people in the group do.)

What word shall I use to relate to this age group?
And how about movies from the forties, the sixties, and the eighties?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Movies ***from the early 2000s***...

Comment: @Jim Errr... thanks. Didn't think about that, that could be used. However I'm trying to find a more generalized adjective (which can also be used to describe  movies from nineties like *The Shawshank Redemption*.)

Comment: I doubt you’ll find a good word for this. I would call them _recent_ movies, but the problem is that if you ask 100 people how they’d describe the age of movies like _The Last Samurai_ and _The Shawshank Redemption_, I suspect you’ll get 50 people calling them ‘new’ and 50 people calling them ‘old’. Most teenagers I know would consider them positively ancient, while most pensioners I know would think of them as having just come out. How do you describe the age of something relatively when people disagree on how relatively old it is?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Well, I'm just asking words, I'm well aware that people may have different opinions, but that doesn't bother me. As long as I can get some other words other than the `new` and `old` in the case you described, it's enough for me. Thanks for mention it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might describe a movie from the last few decades as "modern" or "contemporary".

A movie from the last few years might simply be described as "recent", although that's probably more restrictive than you want.

A particularly old movie might be described by the technical aspects by which it differs from a modern one -- for instance, a "silent film".

Comment: Ah!  So a newer movie is a "talkie"!